# Java - Variables are not updating

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to programming and I am currently trying to complete one of my tutorial's for uni. The point of the tutorial is to set 8 primitive data types, print them, then reassign a new value and print those. The issue I have is when I reassign value of the variable it still prints the original value. My code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class week02tutorial02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte element = 63 ;
    short speed = 1192 ;
    int age = 10;
    long tfn = 987_654_321 ;
    float height = 161.5f ;
    double weight = 80.4 ;
    boolean alive = true ;
    char firstinitial = 'C';

    String tutorial = "Favourite element: " +element+"\n"
            + "Running Speed: "+speed+"kph\n"
            + "Age: "+age+"\n"
            + "Tax File Number: "+tfn+"\n"
            + "Height: "+height+"cm\n"
            + "Weight: "+weight+"Kg\n"
            + "Still Alive: "+alive+"\n"
            + "First Initial: "+firstinitial+"\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tutorial);

    element = 20;
    speed = 512;
    age = 15;
    tfn = 563_435_123;
    height = 120.3f;
    weight = 56.8;
    alive = false;
    firstinitial = 'D';

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tutorial);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to reconstruct the `tutorial` variable.

Comment: You need to generate the string again. It doesn't know about your variables.

Comment: `String`s are **immutable**. Once constructed, they don't change anymore. The `String` is in no way connected to the variables, it just extracts the text data once. You are probably better of outsourcing the construction into some `method`, or even better into a container class with a `toString` method.

Comment: String just store the values of those variables and not references. You need to update the string again to reflect those changes in your string.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate the feedback and help!

Answer (score 0):

You were super close. You need to make sure when you update your values, you also update your tutorial string. Your sting only takes copies of the value you originally gave it. So change the original and the copy doesn't know.

This should work.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class week02tutorial02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte element = 63 ;
    short speed = 1192 ;
    int age = 10;
    long tfn = 987_654_321 ;
    float height = 161.5f ;
    double weight = 80.4 ;
    boolean alive = true ;
    char firstinitial = 'C';

    String tutorial = "Favourite element: " +element+"\n"
        + "Running Speed: "+speed+"kph\n"
        + "Age: "+age+"\n"
        + "Tax File Number: "+tfn+"\n"
        + "Height: "+height+"cm\n"
        + "Weight: "+weight+"Kg\n"
        + "Still Alive: "+alive+"\n"
        + "First Initial: "+firstinitial+"\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tutorial);

    element = 20;
    speed = 512;
    age = 15;
    tfn = 563_435_123;
    height = 120.3f;
    weight = 56.8;
    alive = false;
    firstinitial = 'D';

    //new line to update tutorials values
    tutorial = "Favourite element: " +element+"\n"
        + "Running Speed: "+speed+"kph\n"
        + "Age: "+age+"\n"
        + "Tax File Number: "+tfn+"\n"
        + "Height: "+height+"cm\n"
        + "Weight: "+weight+"Kg\n"
        + "Still Alive: "+alive+"\n"
        + "First Initial: "+firstinitial+"\n";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tutorial);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, John. Now I understand and I appreciate the help immensely.